# Split numpy 2D array based on separate label array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array `A`. For example:

```
A = np.array([[1, 2],
              [3, 4],
              [5, 6],
              [7, 8],
              [9, 0]])
```

I have another label array `B` corresponding to rows of `A`. For example:

```
B = np.array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1])
```

I want to split `A` into 3 arrays based on their labels, so the result would be:

```
[[[1, 2],
  [7, 8]],
 [[3, 4],
  [9, 0]],
 [[5, 6]]]
```

Are there any numpy built in functions to achieve this?

Right now, my solution is rather ugly and involves repeating calling `numpy.where` in a `for`-loop, and slicing the indices tuples to contain only the rows.

Comment: Are the labels always evenly distributed like that? Can the result always become an array?

Comment: Please correct your sample arrays to have commas so we can paste them into a console

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

1. `hstack` both the array together.
2. `sort` the `array` by `the last column`
3. `split` the `array` based on `unique` value `index`

```
a = np.hstack((A,B[:,None]))
a = a[a[:, -1].argsort()]
a = np.split(a[:,:-1], np.unique(a[:, -1], return_index=True)[1][1:])
```

###### OUTPUT:

```
[array([[1, 2],
        [7, 8]]),
 array([[3, 4],
        [9, 0]]),
 array([[5, 6]])]
```

Comment: You can just argsort the labels, which is much faster

Answer (score 1):

If the output can always be an array because the labels are equally distributed, you only need to sort the data by label:

```
idx = B.argsort()
n = np.flatnonzero(np.diff(idx))[0] + 1
result = A[idx].reshape(n, A.shape[0] // n, A.shape[1])
```

If the labels aren't equally distributed, you'll have to make a list in the outer dimension:

```
_, indices, counts = np.unique(B, return_counts=True, return_inverse=True)
result = np.split(A[indices.argsort()], counts.cumsum()[:-1])
```

Using the equivalent of `np.where` is not very efficient, but you can do it without a loop:

```
b, idx = np.unique(B, return_inverse=True)
mask = idx[:, None] == np.arange(b.size)
result = np.split(A[idx.argsort()], np.count_nonzero(mask, axis=0).cumsum()[:-1])
```

You can compute the mask simulataneously for all the labels and apply it to the sorted `A` (`A[idx.argsort()]`) by counting the number of matching elements in each category (`np.count_nonzero(mask, axis=0).cumsum()`). The last index is stripped off the cumulative sum because `np.split` always adds an implicit total index.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Pandas for this because it's designed for labelled data and has a powerful groupby method.

```
import pandas as pd
index = pd.Index(B, name='label')
df = pd.DataFrame(A, index=index)
groups = {k: v.values for k, v in df.groupby('label')}
print(groups)
```

This produces a dictionary of arrays of the grouped values:

```
{0: array([[1, 2],
        [7, 8]]), 1: array([[3, 4],
        [9, 0]]), 2: array([[5, 6]])}
```

For a list of the arrays you can do this instead:

```
groups = [v.values for k, v in df.groupby('label')]
```

Answer (score -1):

This is probably the simplest way:

```
groups = [A[B == label, :] for label in np.unique(B)]
print(groups)
```

Output:

```
[array([[1, 2],
       [7, 8]]), array([[3, 4],
       [9, 0]]), array([[5, 6]])]
```

Comment: OP specifically said they didn't want to loop over a mask on each index